# Searchbox in menu for TYPO3 9.5 LTS

Tags: typoscript, faceted-search, search-box, typo3-9.x

I'm currently developing a Website with the new `TYPO3 9.5` LTS Version and need to implement a search-box.
This search-box should appear on all pages in the menu without any advanced search link or other unnecessary things.
Just a simple input field to search for content on the website.

In the past I did this with the Faceted Search extension ([ke_search](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/ke_search/)).
But this extension currently only supports `TYPO3` up to Version `8.7.99`.

Does anyone already know a possibility to provide the same functionality in `TYPO3 9.5 LTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the moment we created a searchbox with the indexed_search until ke_search is ready for this Typo3 Version.

Our TYPOScript for the searchbox with bootstrap input-group:

```
# Searchbox
lib.searchbox = COA_INT
lib.searchbox {
    10 = TEXT
    10 {
        typolink {
            parameter = 110
            additionalParams = &tx_indexedsearch_pi2[action]=search&tx_indexedsearch_pi2[controller]=Search
            useCacheHash = 1
            returnLast = url
        }
        wrap = <form action="|" method="post" id="search-block-form" class="form-search"><input type="hidden" name="tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][languageUid]" value="0" /><div class="input-group">
    }    
    20 = COA
    20 {
        10 = TEXT
        10.data = GPvar : tx_indexedsearch |sword
        10.wrap ( 
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tx_indexedsearch_pi2[search][sword]" id="tx-indexedsearch-searchbox-sword" placeholder="Suche" />
        )
        20 = COA
        20 {            
            10 = TEXT
            10.value = <span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary"><span class="icon glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span>
        }
    }
    wrap = | </div></form>
}
```

And with this TYPOScript we can add it in the fluid template like this:

```
<section class="searchbox-wrapper">
    <f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.searchbox" />
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you checkout the CORE split of [indexted_search](https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/cms-indexed-search).
Its not that good as ke_search, but maybe you can work with it for now, until ke_search is availible for TYPO3 9.5.x

Answer (score 0):

Get in contact with the owners of ext:ke_search. I assume they are on the way for a new version, which you might can test already.
You also can 'bribe' them with money to get the update done faster. ;-)